# How to pass a variable from a shell script to a mysql script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, variables

I have a bunch of mysql scripts that use **name1** as the database name and populate that database with my data. However, I want to be able to choose the name of the database, instead of always naming it **name1** everywhere in my sql scripts.

I already have a wrapper shell script that takes in the path of my data file and now I would like it to also take in the name of the database.

In my shell script, i assign:

```
DATABASE_NAME=$2
```

Is there any way at the top of my mysql scripts where I can use $DATABASE_NAME? So in the mysql scripts, it would be:

```
USE DATABASE_NAME;
```

instead of what I have right now:

```
USE name1;
```

Comment: How many databases are you using at one time while you are in a script? If 1, then clean up your scripts once.

Comment: I am only using 1 database, called name1. But I have nearly 10 mysql scripts that reference it. Also, what do you mean by "clean up your scripts once"?

Comment: I just don't see the point of people doing `select blah from mydb.table1 ...` with `mydb.` all over the place

Comment: `Ctrl-H` Find and Replace. Poof, `mydb.` goes to blank

Comment: Add your script to your question.

Comment: Well find and replace is an option. But while loading the data from the command line, I want to give who ever is using this program the option to name the database, instead of it always being defined as **name1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mysql -e` to execute your code:

```
mysql -e "USE ${DATABASENAME}; Some sql"
```

That way any replace works.

Optionally you can write temporary sql files or pipeline code into your mysql in which you just replace the `${DATABASENAME}` when parsing that file. (The `-e` option is the most transparent and easiest)

Comment: Ok if I do that, I may have something like `mysql -e "USE ${DATABASENAME}; DataLoad.sql"`. In the DataLoad.sql file, how do I reference the same database name? (for something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM name1.Load` where I want name1 to be replaced by the DATABASENAME)

Comment: @Jain The `USE` command sets the default database. So just leave the database name out of your SQL, e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Load`.

Comment: You can use `source filename.sql` to load the SQL from a file.

Comment: @Barmar I tried that but for some of my sql scripts, it says that the table doesnt exist if I dont have **name1.Load**. I agree with you on the logic, but maybe mysql doesnt

Comment: No its always the same one. Not sure why it isnt working